# xmlrpc.client.Fault when calling TestRun.update()

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Kiwi version 6.0, tcms-api 5.0.

Given that 82 is a valid test run_id and 7 is a valid build_id for the test run's product in the Kiwi instance, run this Python snippet:

```
from tcms_api import TCMS
kiwi = TCMS()
kiwi.exec.TestRun.update(82, {'build' : 7})
```

Expect:
The test run's product build is updated from 1 (unspecified) to 7.

Result:
`Exception has occurred: xmlrpc.client.Fault
<Fault -32603: "Internal error: 'status'">`

There's no other call stack information, so I'm at a loss to further debug. I've tried updating a couple of different fields (manager and status) with the same result. I also get the same result if the value I'm trying to update is unknown/invalid.

Additional information: the equivalent call to TestCaseRun.update() API works. I.e., I can update the build information on a TestCaseRun instance.

Comment: I am assuming 7 is a valid build ID ?  Can you try to reproduce this against https://demo.kiwitcms.org ? We are logging exceptions there so I will be able to see what is going on.  I suspect the problem is around line 262 in tcms/xmlrpc/api/testrun.py

Comment: @AlexanderTodorov It took a little flailing about, but I reproduced this against demo.kiwitcms.org. Look for activity associated with run_id= 548 with a timestamp near 10/18/18 10:22am Pacific Time. Please ignore the first exception, didn't get the script right the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@s-manke. This is a genuine bug. I've implemented a hot-fix here: https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/pull/553
so you can at least continue to use the API.

I am in the process of cutting a new version anyway so this hot-fix will go in. However the API will not process status or stop_date fields at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the quick turn around. For me, this fix is more of a nice to have rather than an absolute blocker. I'll keep an eye out for the next release.